# How can I replace RegionManager instances on Marionette 3

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am currently upgrading a project from Marionette v2 to v3 but it seems all of the functionality of the region manager was added into the View class.

My project has several instances of

```
Marionette.RegionManager.extend({
  regions: {
    ...
  }
})
```

I was wondering if there is a way of directly converting v2 code like this into v3 code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the region manager can be replaced by a view, acting as the root for all other views. It is sufficient to add it to the application as stated in the Application documentation

```
var Mn = require('backbone.marionette');
var RootView = require('./views/root');


var App = Mn.Application.extend({
  region: '#root-element',

  onStart: function() {
    this.showView(new RootView()); // Which is your old region manager
  }
});

var myApp = new App();
myApp.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [3.0 release blog](https://blog.marionettejs.com/2016/08/23/marionette-v3/index.html):

> **RegionManager**
>
> `Marionette.RegionManager` was removed. This publicly exposed class was mostly used as a common
>   class used between `LayoutView` and `Application`.

The [upgrade guide](https://marionettejs.com/docs/v3.0.0/upgrade.html) doesn't seem to mention `RegionManager` at all.

If you are looking for a codemod or something I'm not aware of any. But there is this [marionette-3-patch](https://github.com/marionettejs/marionette-v3-compat#available-patches) for backwards compatibility with marionette 2, which you can use for upgrade and gradually re-write the 2.x syntax manually or create tooling.

Comment: I have tried the upgrading tool and while it does work for many cases it doesn't cover properly the region manager. Would you happen to know a use case where a View uses the functionality of the RegionManager?